# GET and POST requests from ios5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I'm working on making a client for my REST service on the iPhone. I'm a little lost as to how I go about making the GET and POST requests. I make the url from a NSString, convert it to an NSURL and create the NSURLRequest based off of the url. After that I'm pretty lost. Also, sometimes I care about the response, other times I don't. For example, when making a request for a new id, I care about the response because it's the id I'll use to upload my file later, but when I upload the file I don't care because the server doesn't send a response.

Does anyone have some (hopefully)simple sample code that they could point me to / share?

What I have so far:

```
-(NSString *) makeGetRequest:(NSString *)url :(Boolean)careAboutResult
{
    NSString *results = nil;

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSError *reqError;
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    if(careAboutResult == YES)
    {
        //get the result
    }
    return results;
 }
```

In the code I'm testing with, the URL is

```
http://192.168.0.108:8081/TestUploadService/RestfulUpload.svc/id/test123_DOT_png
```

and I'm saying I do care about the result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@nick  its good you have created a NSURLRequest now you just need to create a connection to send this request and receive response, this request is GET request.

To make POST request you will need to use [NSMutableURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableURLRequest) and set its method name and body content. Here in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) you will find how you can do this.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link, I didn't see that when I was looking earlier. It's starting to work now :)